# Product images in Magento not displayed in frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've uploaded some images to one of my Magento products in the backend, but those are not displayed in the frontend.

I'm analysing the Mysql tables:

```
select * from catalog_product_entity where entity_id=10;
select * from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery where entity_id = 10;
select * from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value where value_id in (46,47,48);
```

And I guess the displayed image is here:

```
select thumbnail, small_image, small_image_label, thumbnail_label 
from catalog_product_flat_1 
where entity_id = 10;
```

but when selecting other image and saving changes in the backend, the values in this table don't change...

My cache is disabled, my permissions are ok in /media folder... cannot understand why the image is not displayed...

Comment: Make sure images are not saved on store level. Also try reindexing flat data.

Comment: yeah, that was my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @gulshanmaurya you can post your answer so that user nano  will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure images are not saved on store level.
Switch to store view and see if images are saved on store level. Remove store level values by making "Use Default Value" checkboxes checked and save product.